# jquery running on localhost but not on server

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, mysql, https

JQuery

```
$(function() {
 $(
 "#contactForm input,#contactForm textarea,#contactForm button"
 ).jqBootstrapValidation({
 preventSubmit: true,
 submitError: function($form, event, errors) {
  // additional error messages or events
 },
 submitSuccess: function($form, event) {
  event.preventDefault(); // prevent default submit behaviour

  var cnumber = $("input#cnumber").val();
  var cname = $("input#cname").val();
  var cemail = $("input#cemail").val();
  var cmessage = $("textarea#cmessage").val();

    $this = $("#sendMessageButton");
    $this.prop("disabled", true);
    $.ajax({
      url: "/xcrawl/mail/contact.php",
      type: "POST",
      data: {
        myname: cname,
        mynumber: cnumber,
        myemail: cemail,
        mymessage: cmessage,
      },
      cache: false,
      success: function(response) {
         // document.write(response);
               alert("Please" + response.substring(0, 1));
        if (response.substring(0, 1) == 1) {
          $("#csuccess").html("<div class='alert alert-success'>");
          $("#csuccess > .alert-success")
            .html(
              "<button type='button' class='close' data-dismiss='alert' aria-hidden='true'>&times;"
            )
            .append("</button>");
          $("#csuccess > .alert-success").append(
            "<strong>Thank You for Contacting Us.<br>You will get back to you within 24 Hours<strong>"
          );
          $("#csuccess > .alert-success").append("</div>");
          //clear all fields
          $("#contactForm").trigger("reset");
        } else {
          $("#csuccess").html("<div class='alert alert-success'>");
          $("#csuccess > .alert-success")
            .html(
              "<button type='button' class='close' data-dismiss='alert' aria-hidden='true'>&times;"
            )
            .append("</button>");
          $("#csuccess > .alert-success").append(
            "<strong>Something went wrong.<br>Please try again later<strong>"
          );
          $("#csuccess > .alert-success").append("</div>");
          //clear all fields
          $("#contactForm").trigger("reset");
        }
      },
      error: function() {

        // Fail message
        $("#success").html("<div class='alert alert-danger'>");
        $("#success > .alert-danger")
          .html(
            "<button type='button' class='close' data-dismiss='alert' aria-hidden='true'>&times;"
          )
          .append("</button>");
        $("#success > .alert-danger").append(
          $("<strong>").text(
            "Sorry " +
            firstName +
            ", something went wrong. Please try again later!"
          )
        );
        $("#success > .alert-danger").append("</div>");
        //clear all fields
        $("#contactForm").trigger("reset");
      },
      complete: function() {
        setTimeout(function() {
          $this.prop("disabled", false); // Re-enable submit button when AJAX call is complete
        }, 1000);
      },
    });


},
filter: function() {
  return $(this).is(":visible");
},
});

  $('a[data-toggle="tab"]').click(function(e) {
   e.preventDefault();
   $(this).tab("show");
  });
});

/*When clicking on Full hide fail/success boxes */
$("#name").focus(function() {
$("#success").html("");
});
```

PHP File

```
<?php

$host = "SOME_HOST";
$username = "SOME_NAME";
$password = "SOME_PASSWORD";
$connection = mysqli_connect($host, $username, $password);

$name = strip_tags(htmlspecialchars($_POST['myname']));
$email_address = strip_tags(htmlspecialchars($_POST['myemail']));
$number = strip_tags(htmlspecialchars($_POST['mynumber']));
$message = strip_tags(htmlspecialchars($_POST['mymessage']));


if(!$connection)
 die("Error : " . mysqli_error());

$DBQuery = "USE MY_DB";
mysqli_query($connection, $DBQuery);

$Query = "MY_QUERY";

if(mysqli_query($connection, $Query))
 echo json_encode (1);
else
 echo json_encode (2);

mysqli_close($connection);

?>
```

This works perfectly on my localhost and it used to work perfectly on my server too 3 days ago.
I bought an SSL and made my site https. Im sure that that is the reason because there cannot be any other reason why it would work on localhost and not on server. But im not using any http links. So why isnt it working on my server?
The response Code should be either 1 or 2 according to my php code  but im getting the whole php file as response. Please help me out

**EDIT**
Index.html

```
 <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.5.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
 <script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.5.0/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js"></script>
 <!-- Third party plugin JS-->
 <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery-easing/1.4.1/jquery.easing.min.js"></script>
 <!-- Contact form JS-->
 <script src="xcrawl/mail/jqBootstrapValidation.js"></script>
 <script src="xcrawl/mail/contact_me.js"></script>
 <!-- Core theme JS-->
 <script src="xcrawl/js/scripts.js"></script>
```

Comment: What doesnt work? What is the error message? Could you show the HTML?

Comment: The responose code im getting should have been 1 or 2, but im getting the whole php code as response @Achtung

Comment: That means your server is not processing the PHP logic but instead reading it as text. Are you sure your server supports PHP at all? If it does, then you need to configure it properly.

Comment: If you get the actual PHP code as responce there is something wrong with your server settings. Since it should always at least try to render your php files.

Comment: But except my index file, every other file is php file. @Achtung

Comment: @Prateek BB Im not sure i understand what you mean with that. But if the server returns the php code there is something wrong with its configuration. Perhaps post it here also. But i dont know enought about such things to help really.

Comment: Il reconfirm hold on @Achtung

Comment: Thank you so much @Achtung
Please answer and i'll accept it

Comment: I dont know how i could have missed such a thing